# Discord.js Bot giveaway command:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to code a giveaway command but this problem pop up on my face

> (node:2052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
> args[1].endswith is not a function (node:2052)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:2052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ")
  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}giveaway`)) {
    let time = args[1]
    if(!time) return message.channel.send('**You did not specify your time!**');
    if(
    !args[1].endsWith('d') &&
    !args[1].endsWith('h') &&
    !args[1].endsWith('m') &&
    !args[1].endsWith('s')
   )
    return message.channel.send('**You need to use d (days), h (hours), m (minutes), s (seconds)**')

let gchannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
if(!gchannel) return message.channel.send('**I can not find this channel!**')

let prize = args.slice(3).join(" ")
if(!prize) return message.channel.send('**What is the prize?**')

message.delete();
gchannel.send(":tada: **NEW GIVEAWAY** :tada:")
let gembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setTitle('New GIVEAWAY!')
.setDescription(`react with :tada: to enter the giveaway! \nHosted by **${message.author}**\nTime: **${time}**`)
.setTimestamp(Date.now + ms(args[1]))
.setFooter('Will end at:')
let m = await gchannel.send(gembed)
m.react("")
setTimeout(() => {
  if(m.reactions.cache.get("").count <= 1) {
    return message.channel.send('**No enough people reacted for mr to draw a winner!**')
  }

let winner = m.reactions.cache.get("").users.cache.filter((u) => !u.bot).random();
gchannel.send(`CONGRATULATIONS ${winner}! you just won the **${prize}!**`
);
}, ms(args[1]));
  }
   })
```

any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `endsWith` not endswith. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith